# php rand() omitting leading zeros

Tags: php, random

Hi am using the following to gen a 4 char numeric

```
 $this->pin = rand(0000,9999)
```

however if the result is 0435 the leading zero is omitted. How can I keep the leading zero in the result?

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeroes, numbers formatted as strings have leading zeroes `$this->pin = sprint('%04d', rand(0000,9999));` though you're better formatting just at the point where you want to display

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Just a point I always like to submit when seeing rand, use mt_rand for a better random value.

Answer (score 4):

You can also:

```
$number = rand(0,9999);
$this->pin = str_pad($number,4,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer is not a string, so you can't have a leading zero! :-P
However you can do:

```
function zfill($str,$n){
  $ret = $str;
  while(strlen($ret)<$n){
    $ret = '0'.$ret;
  }
  return $ret;
}

$this->pin = zfill($this->pin, 4);
```

Comment: Erm, why write your own version of `str_pad`? )